# return value after event from applet to javaScript

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

I am really confused while working with Applet. Actually, I am new for Applet and my project is very crusial stage so please help me.
What I am doing: my javascript function calls applet method that method get all installed certificates from browser and show it on applet window, now user will select one of them and press OK button. On click of OK button user will get some values from certificate to jsp page. But I am confused here how to pass that value back to jsp after completion of actionPerformed method.

**My Applet class:**

```
public class CertificateChooser extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public Object[] colledMethod(){
    //Created and configured required components here...
    okButton.setText("OK");
    okButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            okButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    }
    private void okButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex() != 0){
            //some logic goes here...
            }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Jacob is your friend. I worked on same using JACOB

Comment: Have a look how this works here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html 
The way to go is to use the 'JSObject'